# boost::mpl: How to generate pre-generated header files for lists with more than 50 entries?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-mpl

I want to code a state machine which has a reaction list with more than 50 entries.

I found [here](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/libs/mpl/preprocessed/) some python scripts to generate header files for lists with more than 50 entries.

But I cannot manage to generate a single header file. Can someone please explain to me how to use theses scripts? I also didn't find any help in boost documention.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: how many do you need?

Comment: I think 60 or 70 for now.

Answer (score 6):

**Important Update:**

A more improved script, which only requires a working *python* environment is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29627158/3115457) to this question.

**Original Answer**

See my [answer](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.user/80497) to your [question](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.user/80439) on the Boost mailing-list.

The following bash-code will generate the MPL-containers for 51 to 100 entries. If you do not care about the other MPL-container types and just want to generate MPL-lists, adjust the value of `CONTAINERS` accordingly.

```
#! /bin/bash

# The name of this script.
SCRIPT_NAME=$(basename $0)
# The usage message for this script.
USAGE="Usage:  ${SCRIPT_NAME} <path-to-boost-source> [<new-value-for BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_VECTOR_SIZE>]"

# Script-arguments:
# The (absolute) path to the directory containing the Boost-source.
SOURCE=$(readlink -e "$1")
# The new limit for Boost.MPL's vector.
NEW_BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_VECTOR_SIZE=$2

# Check validity of arguments.
if [[ -z "${SOURCE}" ]] || ! [[ -d "${SOURCE}" ]]; then
  echo "Missing path to Boost directory."
  echo ${USAGE}
  exit
fi
REGEX_INTEGER='^[0-9]+$'
if [[ -n "${NEW_BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_VECTOR_SIZE}" ]] && ! [[ ${NEW_BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_VECTOR_SIZE} =~ ${REGEX_INTEGER} ]]; then
  echo "New size for BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_VECTOR_SIZE must be an unsigned integer!"
  echo ${USAGE}
  exit
fi


# The Boost.MPL-containers for which more preprocessed
# header-files shall be generated.
CONTAINERS="vector list set map"
# The same containers without Boost.MPL-map.
CONTAINERS_WITHOUT_MAP=$(echo ${CONTAINERS} | sed 's/map//g')

# Change into include-directory of Boost.MPL.
pushd ${SOURCE}/boost/mpl  >/dev/null 2>&1

# Possibly change the limit for Boost.MPL's vector.
if [[ -n "${NEW_BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_VECTOR_SIZE}" ]]; then
  sed -i "s/\(define\s\+BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_VECTOR_SIZE\s\+\)[0-9]\+/\1${NEW_BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_VECTOR_SIZE}/" ./limits/vector.hpp
fi

# Create hpp-files for each MPL-container with 60 to 100 elements
# which will be used during generation.
for container in ${CONTAINERS}; do
  for i in {6..10}; do
    sed -e "s/50/${i}0/g" \
        -e "s/41/$((i-1))1/g" \
        -e "s/40/$((i-1))0/g" \
        ./${container}/${container}50.hpp \
      > ./${container}/${container}${i}0.hpp;
  done
done
for container in ${CONTAINERS_WITHOUT_MAP}; do
  for i in {6..10}; do
    sed -e "s/50/${i}0/g" \
        -e "s/41/$((i-1))1/g" \
        -e "s/40/$((i-1))0/g" \
        ./${container}/${container}50_c.hpp \
      > ./${container}/${container}${i}0_c.hpp;
  done
done

# Leave include-directory of Boost.MPL.
popd  >/dev/null 2>&1
# Change into source-directory of Boost.MPL.
pushd ${SOURCE}/libs/mpl/preprocessed  >/dev/null 2>&1

# Create cpp-files for each MPL-container with 60 to 100 elements
# which will be used during generation.
for container in ${CONTAINERS}; do
  for i in {6..10}; do
    sed -e "s/50/${i}0/g" \
        -e "s/41/$((i-1))1/g" \
        -e "s/40/$((i-1))0/g" \
        ./${container}/${container}50.cpp \
      > ./${container}/${container}${i}0.cpp;
  done
done
for container in ${CONTAINERS_WITHOUT_MAP}; do
  for i in {6..10}; do
    sed -e "s/50/${i}0/g" \
        -e "s/41/$((i-1))1/g" \
        -e "s/40/$((i-1))0/g" \
        ./${container}/${container}50_c.cpp \
      > ./${container}/${container}${i}0_c.cpp;
  done
done

# Now generate MPL-preprocessed files using the python-scripts.
python preprocess_vector.py all ${SOURCE}
python preprocess_list.py   all ${SOURCE}
python preprocess_set.py    all ${SOURCE}
python preprocess_map.py    all ${SOURCE}
python preprocess.py        all ${SOURCE}

# Leave source-directory of Boost.MPL.
popd  >/dev/null 2>&1
```

For even bigger containers with more than 100 entries, adjust the range in the for-loops.

I hope that helps.
Deniz

**Update:**

I realized that my original version of the script did only generate the numbered versions of the MPL-container headers. However, it did not update the non-numbered versions.

I fixed it by adding `python preprocess.py all ${SOURCE}` near the end of the script.
However, this does only generate modified versions of the non-numbered MPL-container headers if during generation the corresponding macro settings (e.g. a higher value for `BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_VECTOR_SIZE`) are different than the original values.

These modifications can be made in the file `user.hpp` within each subdirectory of `${SOURCE}/libs/mpl/preprocessed/include`.

For example, by adding

```
#define BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_VECTOR_SIZE 30
```

to `${SOURCE}/libs/mpl/preprocessed/include/gcc/user.hpp` the `boost::mpl::vector` (included from `boost/mpl/vector.hpp`) is able to hold 30 elements, now, instead of the default 20.

**Note:**

However, it might not be a good idea to adjust values like `BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_VECTOR_SIZE` only for generation and leave its value defined in `${SOURCE}/boost/mpl/limits/vector.hpp` untouched.
Possibly, this does not even compile because the underlying `boost::mpl::vector21` to `boost::mpl::vectorN` cannot be found (because not being included automatically).
Best solution is probably to adjust the value in `${SOURCE}/boost/mpl/limits/vector.hpp`. The above bash-script can automatically do so, if the second (optional) argument is given.

Answer (score 5):

## Final Update

From **Boost 1.59.0** on the below explained scripts are now included in each Boost release.

They are located int *<boost-source-dir>/libs/mpl/preprocessed/*.

The *README.txt* in that directory should explain you how to use it. (Or just read on.)

## Original answer

Because I realized that not everyone has a working **bash** shell at hand (yes, I mean you Windows-guys ;-)) but everyone needs a working **python** environment, I converted my helper bash-script I mentioned [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20660264/3115457) into python:

**boost_mpl_preprocess.py**

```
# Copyright Deniz Bahadir 2015
#
# Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. 
# (See accompanying file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at 
# http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
#
# See http://www.boost.org/libs/mpl for documentation.
# See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20660264/3115457 for further information.
# See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29627158/3115457 for further information.

import argparse
import sys
import os
import os.path
import re
import fileinput
import shutil


def create_more_container_files(sourceDir, suffix, maxElements, containers, containers2):
    """Creates additional files for the individual MPL-containers."""

    # Create files for each MPL-container with 20 to 'maxElements' elements
    # which will be used during generation.
    for container in containers:
        for i in range(20, maxElements, 10):
            # Create copy of "template"-file.
            newFile = os.path.join( sourceDir, container, container + str(i+10) + suffix )
            shutil.copyfile( os.path.join( sourceDir, container, container + "20" + suffix ), newFile ) 
            # Adjust copy of "template"-file accordingly.
            for line in fileinput.input( newFile, inplace=1, mode="rU" ):
                line = re.sub(r'20', re.escape(str(i+10)), line.rstrip())
                line = re.sub(r'11', re.escape(str(i + 1)), line.rstrip())
                line = re.sub(r'10(?![0-9])', re.escape(str(i)), line.rstrip())
                print(line)
    for container in containers2:
        for i in range(20, maxElements, 10):
            # Create copy of "template"-file.
            newFile = os.path.join( sourceDir, container, container + str(i+10) + "_c" + suffix )
            shutil.copyfile( os.path.join( sourceDir, container, container + "20_c" + suffix ), newFile ) 
            # Adjust copy of "template"-file accordingly.
            for line in fileinput.input( newFile, inplace=1, mode="rU" ):
                line = re.sub(r'20', re.escape(str(i+10)), line.rstrip())
                line = re.sub(r'11', re.escape(str(i + 1)), line.rstrip())
                line = re.sub(r'10(?![0-9])', re.escape(str(i)), line.rstrip())
                print(line)


def create_input_for_numbered_sequences(headerDir, sourceDir, containers, maxElements):
    """Creates additional source- and header-files for the numbered sequence MPL-containers."""
    # Create additional container-list without "map".
    containersWithoutMap = containers[:]
    try:
        containersWithoutMap.remove('map')
    except ValueError:
        # We can safely ignore if "map" is not contained in 'containers'!
        pass
    # Create header/source-files.
    create_more_container_files(headerDir, ".hpp", maxElements, containers, containersWithoutMap)
    create_more_container_files(sourceDir, ".cpp", maxElements, containers, containersWithoutMap)


def adjust_container_limits_for_variadic_sequences(headerDir, containers, maxElements):
    """Adjusts the limits of variadic sequence MPL-containers."""
    for container in containers:
        headerFile = os.path.join( headerDir, "limits", container + ".hpp" )
        regexMatch   = r'(define\s+BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_' + container.upper() + r'_SIZE\s+)[0-9]+'
        regexReplace = r'\g<1>' + re.escape( str(maxElements) )
        for line in fileinput.input( headerFile, inplace=1, mode="rU" ):
            line = re.sub(regexMatch, regexReplace, line.rstrip())
            print(line)


def to_positive_multiple_of_10(string):
    """Converts a string into its encoded positive integer (greater zero) or throws an exception."""
    try:
        value = int(string)
    except ValueError:
        msg = '"%r" is not a positive multiple of 10 (greater zero).' % string
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(msg)
    if value <= 0 or value % 10 != 0:
        msg = '"%r" is not a positive multiple of 10 (greater zero).' % string
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(msg)
    return value


def to_existing_absolute_path(string):
    """Converts a path into its absolute path and verifies that it exists or throws an exception."""
    value = os.path.abspath(string)
    if not os.path.exists( value ) or not os.path.isdir( value ):
        msg = '"%r" is not a valid path to a directory.' % string
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(msg)
    return value


def main():
    """The main function."""

    # Prepare and run cmdline-parser.
    cmdlineParser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="A generator-script for pre-processed Boost.MPL headers.")
    cmdlineParser.add_argument("-v", "--verbose", dest='verbose', action='store_true',
                               help="Be a little bit more verbose.")
    cmdlineParser.add_argument("-s", "--sequence-type", dest='seqType', choices=['variadic', 'numbered', 'both'],
                               default='both',
                               help="Only update pre-processed headers for the selected sequence types, "
                                    "either 'numbered' sequences, 'variadic' sequences or 'both' sequence "
                                    "types. (Default=both)")
    cmdlineParser.add_argument("--no-vector", dest='want_vector', action='store_false',
                               help="Do not update pre-processed headers for Boost.MPL Vector.")
    cmdlineParser.add_argument("--no-list", dest='want_list', action='store_false',
                               help="Do not update pre-processed headers for Boost.MPL List.")
    cmdlineParser.add_argument("--no-set", dest='want_set', action='store_false',
                               help="Do not update pre-processed headers for Boost.MPL Set.")
    cmdlineParser.add_argument("--no-map", dest='want_map', action='store_false',
                               help="Do not update pre-processed headers for Boost.MPL Map.")
    cmdlineParser.add_argument("--num-elements", dest='numElements', metavar="<num-elements>",
                               type=to_positive_multiple_of_10, default=100,
                               help="The maximal number of elements per container sequence. (Default=100)")
    cmdlineParser.add_argument(dest='sourceDir', metavar="<source-dir>",
                               type=to_existing_absolute_path,
                               help="The source-directory of Boost.")
    args = cmdlineParser.parse_args()

    # Some verbose debug output.
    if args.verbose:
        print "Arguments extracted from command-line:"
        print "  verbose          = ", args.verbose
        print "  source directory = ", args.sourceDir
        print "  num elements     = ", args.numElements
        print "  sequence type    = ", args.seqType
        print "  want: vector     = ", args.want_vector
        print "  want: list       = ", args.want_list
        print "  want: set        = ", args.want_set
        print "  want: map        = ", args.want_map

    # The directories for header- and source files of Boost.MPL.    
    # NOTE: Assuming 'args.sourceDir' is the source-directory of the entire boost project.
    headerDir = os.path.join( args.sourceDir, "boost", "mpl" )
    sourceDir = os.path.join( args.sourceDir, "libs", "mpl", "preprocessed" )
    # Check that the header/source-directories exist.
    if not os.path.exists( headerDir ) or not os.path.exists( sourceDir ):
        # Maybe 'args.sourceDir' is not the source-directory of the entire boost project
        # but instead of the Boost.MPL git-directory, only?
        headerDir = os.path.join( args.sourceDir, "include", "boost", "mpl" )
        sourceDir = os.path.join( args.sourceDir, "preprocessed" )
        if not os.path.exists( headerDir ) or not os.path.exists( sourceDir ):
            cmdlineParser.print_usage()
            print "error: Cannot find Boost.MPL header/source files in given Boost source-directory!"
            sys.exit(0)

    # Some verbose debug output.
    if args.verbose:
        print "Chosen header-directory: ", headerDir
        print "Chosen source-directory: ", sourceDir

    # Create list of containers for which files shall be pre-processed.
    containers = []
    if args.want_vector:
        containers.append('vector')
    if args.want_list:
        containers.append('list')
    if args.want_set:
        containers.append('set')
    if args.want_map:
        containers.append('map')
    if containers == []:
        print "Nothing to do. (Why did you prevent generating pre-processed headers for all Boost.MPL container types?"
        sys.exit(0)

    # Some verbose debug output.
    if args.verbose:
        print "Containers for which to pre-process headers: ", containers

    # Create (additional) input files for generating pre-processed headers of numbered sequence MPL containers.
    if args.seqType == "both" or args.seqType == "numbered":
        create_input_for_numbered_sequences(headerDir, sourceDir, containers, args.numElements)
    # Modify settings for generating pre-processed headers of variadic sequence MPL containers.
    if args.seqType == "both" or args.seqType == "variadic":
        adjust_container_limits_for_variadic_sequences(headerDir, containers, args.numElements)

    # Generate MPL-preprocessed files.
    os.chdir( sourceDir )
    if args.seqType == "both" or args.seqType == "numbered":
        if args.want_vector:
            if args.verbose:
                print "Pre-process headers for Boost.MPL numbered vectors."
            os.system( "python " + os.path.join( sourceDir, "preprocess_vector.py" ) + " all " + args.sourceDir )
        if args.want_list:
            if args.verbose:
                print "Pre-process headers for Boost.MPL numbered lists."
            os.system( "python " + os.path.join( sourceDir, "preprocess_list.py" ) + " all " + args.sourceDir )
        if args.want_set:
            if args.verbose:
                print "Pre-process headers for Boost.MPL numbered sets."
            os.system( "python " + os.path.join( sourceDir, "preprocess_set.py" ) + " all " + args.sourceDir )
        if args.want_map:
            if args.verbose:
                print "Pre-process headers for Boost.MPL numbered maps."
            os.system( "python " + os.path.join( sourceDir, "preprocess_map.py" ) + " all " + args.sourceDir )
    if args.seqType == "both" or args.seqType == "variadic":
        if args.verbose:
            print "Pre-process headers for Boost.MPL variadic containers."
        os.system( "python " + os.path.join( sourceDir, "preprocess.py" ) + " all " + args.sourceDir )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Running it with

```
python boost_mpl_preprocess.py --help
```

gives some usage information.

But you can also just run it with a single command-line parameter which determines the path to the Boost source-directory (e.g. `python boost_mpl_preprocess.py ./boost-source`) and use the default behavior.

This results in creating preprocessed headers for all four Boost.MPL container types (`vector`, `list`, `set` and `map`) with their [*numbered* and *variadic*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/variadic-sequence.html) form.

**Note:**

As a side effect when preprocessing Boost.MPL containers in their *variadic* form, the value of their associated limit-macros `BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_container_SIZE` will be modified, too. It gets the number of elements determined when calling **boost_mpl_preprocess.py**.

For example, the following call preprocesses only the *variadic* form of Boost.MPL `vector` and also sets the macro `BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_VECTOR_SIZE` in `./boost-source/boost/mpl/limits/vector.hpp` to `70`.

```
$ python boost_mpl_preprocess.py --no-list --no-set --no-map \
    --sequence-type=variadic --num-elements=70 ./boost-source
```

### Update

Since Boost 1.56 pre-processing Boost.MPL containers even with the above script did no longer work, because of changes in the header-comments, the original python-scripts relied on.

The following script can be used to fix this problem. It just adds the missing information into the header-comments.

**fix_boost_mpl_preprocess.py**

```
# Copyright Deniz Bahadir 2015
#
# Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. 
# (See accompanying file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at 
# http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
#
# See http://www.boost.org/libs/mpl for documentation.
# See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29627158/3115457 for further information.

import argparse
import sys
import os.path
import re
import fileinput
import datetime
import glob


def fix_header_comment(filename, timestamp):
    """Fixes the header-comment of the given file."""
    # Fix input file.
    name = os.path.basename( filename )
    for line in fileinput.input( filename, inplace=1, mode="rU" ):
        # If header-comment already contains anything for '$Id$', remove it.
        line = re.sub(r'\$Id:[^$]+\$', r'$Id$', line.rstrip())
        # Replace '$Id$' by a string containing the file's name (and a timestamp)!
        line = re.sub(re.escape(r'$Id$'), r'$Id: ' + name + r' ' + timestamp.isoformat() + r' $', line.rstrip())
        print(line)


def fix_input_files_for_variadic_seq(sourceDir, timestamp):
    """Fixes files used as input when pre-processing MPL-containers in their variadic form."""
    files = glob.glob( os.path.join( sourceDir, "src", "*" ) )
    for currentFile in sorted( files ):
        fix_header_comment( currentFile, timestamp )


def fix_input_files_for_numbered_seq(sourceDir, suffix, timestamp, containers):
    """Fixes files used as input when pre-processing MPL-containers in their numbered form."""
    # Fix input files for each MPL-container type.
    for container in containers:
        files = glob.glob( os.path.join( sourceDir, container, container + '*' + suffix ) )
        for currentFile in sorted( files ):
            fix_header_comment( currentFile, timestamp )


def fix_input_files(headerDir, sourceDir, containers=['vector', 'list', 'set', 'map'], verbose='false'):
    """Fixes source- and header-files used as input when pre-processing MPL-containers."""
    # The new modification time.
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.now();
    # Fix the input files.
    if verbose:
        print "Fix input files for pre-processing Boost.MPL variadic containers."
    fix_input_files_for_variadic_seq(sourceDir, timestamp)
    if verbose:
        print "Fix input files for pre-processing Boost.MPL numbered containers."
    fix_input_files_for_numbered_seq(headerDir, ".hpp", timestamp, containers)
    fix_input_files_for_numbered_seq(sourceDir, ".cpp", timestamp, containers)


def to_existing_absolute_path(string):
    """Converts a path into its absolute path and verifies that it exists or throws an exception."""
    value = os.path.abspath(string)
    if not os.path.exists( value ) or not os.path.isdir( value ):
        msg = '"%r" is not a valid path to a directory.' % string
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(msg)
    return value


def main():
    """The main function."""

    # Prepare and run cmdline-parser.
    cmdlineParser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
                    description="Fixes the input files used for pre-processing of Boost.MPL headers.")
    cmdlineParser.add_argument("-v", "--verbose", dest='verbose', action='store_true',
                               help="Be a little bit more verbose.")
    cmdlineParser.add_argument(dest='sourceDir', metavar="<source-dir>",
                               type=to_existing_absolute_path,
                               help="The source-directory of Boost.")
    args = cmdlineParser.parse_args()

    # Some verbose debug output.
    if args.verbose:
        print "Arguments extracted from command-line:"
        print "  verbose           = ", args.verbose
        print "  source directory  = ", args.sourceDir

    # The directories for header- and source files of Boost.MPL.    
    # NOTE: Assuming 'args.sourceDir' is the source-directory of the entire boost project.
    headerDir = os.path.join( args.sourceDir, "boost", "mpl" )
    sourceDir = os.path.join( args.sourceDir, "libs", "mpl", "preprocessed" )
    # Check that the header/source-directories exist.
    if not os.path.exists( headerDir ) or not os.path.exists( sourceDir ):
        # Maybe 'args.sourceDir' is not the source-directory of the entire boost project
        # but instead of the Boost.MPL git-directory, only?
        headerDir = os.path.join( args.sourceDir, "include", "boost", "mpl" )
        sourceDir = os.path.join( args.sourceDir, "preprocessed" )
        if not os.path.exists( headerDir ) or not os.path.exists( sourceDir ):
            cmdlineParser.print_usage()
            print "error: Cannot find Boost.MPL header/source files in given Boost source-directory!"
            sys.exit(0)

    # Some verbose debug output.
    if args.verbose:
        print "Chosen header-directory: ", headerDir
        print "Chosen source-directory: ", sourceDir

    # Fix input file for generating pre-processed headers.
    fix_input_files(headerDir, sourceDir, verbose = args.verbose)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Run it like so:

```
$ python fix-boost_mpl_preprocess.py ./boost-source
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what is exactly your problem. Which state-machine you use...
But perhaps this link helps:
http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2004/08/70900.php

Comment: My problem is that boost provides pre-generated header file for up to 50 entries for a list, vector etc. I know about this mailing list entry but I want to generate pre-generated header files myself for list with 60 or more entries.